# Can I play my PS3 on my 21" iMac?

Tags: ps3

Im finding it difficult to come to a clear conclusion. There are thunderbolt to HDMI adaptors out there. Will the iMac be able to be used as a monitor?

Comment: Depends if Thumberbolt to HDMI adapters and the iMac work properly with HDCP. I know the PS3's HDMI uses HDCP which can be an issue but I don't know whether it is an issue with thunderbolt/iMacs

Answer (score 2):

Nope. Target Display Mode, where you can use newer iMac screens as external displays for other Macs, are available as special features of Macs via Mini Displayport and Thunderbolt connections. They are NOT a standard display technology and unless you're running through a special conversion box/software specifically for TDM, this won't work. AFAIK, there are no such third party tools at the moment.

Comment: That's why I don't buy Macs. They're great pieces of hardware, but they don't play very nice with anything that's not from Apple. It's like they don't care about anyone other than themselves, really. Sorry if this starts a debate.

Comment: Same with the consoles manufacturers themselves though, if PS3 allowed you to connect via VNC, you could happily control it through the Mac. Remote play to the Vita is essentially VNC.